# The difference between 'credit' and 'accredit'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences, meaning-in-context

Both verbs seem to mean the same thing -- to attribute 'X' to Mr. 'Y'. On looking it up, I found:

credit - publicly acknowledge a contributor's role in the production of (something published or broadcast).

accredit - give credit to (someone) for something.

Am I overthinking this, or is there really a difference I should know of?

Comment: it's a good question!

Comment: Inadequate research. Please research the words further. Please also visit [ELL.SE]

Answer (score 5):

1. The definitions of *credit* and *accredit* clearly overlap at ***acknowledging the role of another***. The semantic overlap:

> *[credit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credit)*
>   verb (credits, crediting, credited)
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1.0 ***Publicly acknowledge*** a contributor’s role
>   in the production of (something published or broadcast):
>   *the
>   screenplay is credited to one American and two Japanese writers*
>
> 1.1 (credit someone with) ***Ascribe*** (an achievement or good quality) ***to someone***:
>   *he is credited with painting one hundred and twenty-five
>   canvases*
>
> *[accredit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accredit)*
>   verb (accredits, accrediting, accredited)
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1.0 ***Give credit to*** (someone) for something:
>   *he was accredited with being one of the world’s fastest sprinters*
>
> 1.1 (accredit something to) ***Attribute an action, saying, or quality to***:
>   *the discovery of distillation is usually accredited to the Arabs*
>
> *ODO **Emphasis** mine*

The semantic similarities are reinforced by the syntactical similarities:

> 1. The work is *credited* **to** the person, and the work is *accredited* **to** the person
> 2. The person is *credited* **with** the work, and the person is *accredited* **with** the work.

---

2. The words *credit* and *accredit* have each expanded separately into different uses. *Credit* dominates **financial** contexts, while *accredit* dominates **authorization** contexts:

> *[credit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credit)*
>
> 2.0 Add (an amount of money) to
>   an account: this deferred tax can be credited to the profit and loss
>   account
>   3.0 [OFTEN WITH MODAL] British Believe
>   (something surprising or unlikely): you would hardly credit it—but it
>   was true
>
> *[accredit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accredit)*
>   2.0 (Of an official body) give authority or
>   sanction to (someone or something) when recognized standards have been
>   met:
>   *institutions that do not meet the standards will not be
>   accredited for teacher training*
>   (as adjective accredited)  *an
>   accredited practitioner*
>
> 3.0 Give official
>   authorization for (someone, typically a diplomat or journalist) to be
>   in a particular place or to hold a particular post:
>   *no journalist
>   accredited to the UN has ever been expelled*

---

3. By loose association with its numerous noun form uses, *[credit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credit)* tends to be a more general term than *accredit*. *[Credit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=credit&allowed_in_frame=0)* entered English from French in the early 16th century as a noun and then extended into use as a verb:

> n.
>   1520s, from Middle French crédit (15c.) "belief, trust,"
>   from Italian
>   credito,
>   from Latin creditum "a loan, thing entrusted to another,"
>   from past participle of credere "to trust, entrust, believe" (see
>   credo).
>   The commercial sense was the original one in English (creditor
>   is mid-15c.).
>   Meaning "honor, acknowledgment of merit," is from c.
>   1600.
>   Academic sense of "point for completing a course of study" is 1904.
>   Movie/broadcasting sense is 1914.
>   Credit rating is from 1958;
>   credit union is 1881, American English.
>
> v. 1540s, from credit (n.). Related: Credited; crediting.
>
> *etymonline.com*

*[Accredit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=accredit&allowed_in_frame=0)* entered English directly as a verb about 70 years after *credit* began extending to its verbal use:

> 1610s, from French accréditer, from à "to" (see ad-) + créditer "to
>   credit" (someone with a sum), from crédit "credit" (see credit (n.)).
>
> *etymonline.com*

Answer (score 3):

Credit generally refers to the definition you gave. The definition you found for accredit is a secondary one, though. Accredit is generally used in a different context, to mean: "to give official authorization to or approval of".
See Merriam's definitions for accredit:

```
1. to give official authorization to or approval of
2. to give recognition to (someone or something) for doing something
```

Both are valid, but the first is more common. The second is equivalent to credit.